# how install wget ver>18 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, wget

I need to install wget newer version >=18 on ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

installs wget 17 version

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is in it's last days of *standard* support (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) so I'd suggest you instead plan your upgrade to 18.04 LTS and your issue will be solved anyway.  (you'll then be using `wget 1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2` and problem is solved)

Comment: Might be an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?